# CGAL seam_mesh: how to include the seam in the halfedge_descriptor of the boundary?

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal, parameterization

I am parametrizing a simple mesh (see the picture below) with the [seam_Polyhedron_3.cpp](https://doc.cgal.org/4.14.3/Surface_mesh_parameterization/Surface_mesh_parameterization_2seam_Polyhedron_3_8cpp-example.html) example of CGAL 4.14.

[image: simple example mesh]

I identified the vertices to "cut it open" that I wrote into a seam file (they lie along one polyline connecting the lower and upper boundary):

```
73 75 80 120
```

However, I am confused about what the line

```cpp
halfedge_descriptor bhd = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::longest_border(mesh).first;
```

returns: it seems to iterate through the lower boundary only. This I could check by counting the vertices on the boundary,

```cpp
typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Mesh>::vertex_descriptor Mesh_vertex_descriptor;
Mesh_vertex_descriptor beg = source(bhd, mesh);
int i=0;
do
{
    i++;
    bhd = next(bhd, mesh);
}
while(source(bhd, mesh) != beg);
std::cout << "There were " << i << " vertices on the boundary." << std::endl;
```

which returned 34 (which, in turn, is the number of vertices on the lower boundary).

**Question:** How can I modify the construction of `bhd` so that it encompasses the *entire* (virtual) boundary? I.e., the iteration I just showed should iterate through the lower boundary, seam upwards, upper boundary and the seam downwards and return 32 + 3 + 32 + 3 = 70?

So far I tried to find an alternative to [longest_boundary](https://doc.cgal.org/4.14.3/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__measure__grp.html#ga766d9244b959bc25e419edb8b7c24842) and to see if there is a possibility to modify the behaviour through the [named parameters](https://doc.cgal.org/4.14.3/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__pmp__namedparameters.html). I also tried adding the vertices on the lower and upper boundaries to the mesh but this does not change anything, as noted in the documentation of [Seam_mesh](https://doc.cgal.org/4.14.3/BGL/classCGAL_1_1Seam__mesh.html). Reversing the order of the seam vertices also made no visible change.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `mesh` the seam_mesh or the underlying surface_mesh ? Did you check that your polyline file was correctly read ? Did you try adding it manually with `Seam_mesh::add_seam()` ? I really don't think it is a  `longest_boundary()` behavior problem, either it is a bug, or your seam mesh is not what you think.

Comment: @mgimeno `mesh` is the seam_mesh. I will try adding the seam manually. How can I check that the polyline is correct? All I can think of now would be to try and print the coordinates of its vertices.

Comment: You can open the file in a stream and test the stream, with something like `std::ifstream in("yourfile.txt"); if(!in) std::cerr<<"file not found"<<std::endl;`

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the example already checks if `add_seams` has returned a halfedge. I did not want to post the example (it is from the documentation and the question would be quite long then) but it would probably have been better, because we would have the source code in front of us.

Comment: In any case @mgimeno's comment helped me understand what was wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of @mgimeno helped me understand what was wrong. I post it as an answer in case someone else will be confused about the structure of `.selection.txt` files in future (see also a [related discussion](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Planar-Parameterization-of-Triangulated-Surface-Meshes-td4663896.html)).

Here once again the mesh but with the labels of the vertices along which I want to cut.

[image: mesh with labeled vertices]

**Tip:** To find these numbers in your mesh, open it in Meshlab and click Render > Show Labels. It works well with meshes in .off format but is likely to run into problemw with .stl, where the order of vertices is not specified.

Based on the documentation of [Seam_mesh::add_seam(..)](https://doc.cgal.org/4.14.3/BGL/classCGAL_1_1Seam__mesh.html#a27d5997959e6a348e7206e359a378d85) we need to add three seam edges. Each of these edges is given by the indices of its endpoints. A correct format of `seam.selection.txt` is then

```
73 75 75 80 80 120
```

Note the duplicities (each vertex is there once as a starting point and once as an endpoint) and the two leading empty lines.

The boundary now has 70 vertices (I was repeatedly off-by-one in the original version of my question).